# Get current page URL and Title from a SharePoint Provider Hosted add-in Part?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, cross-domain, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I'm looking to see if there is a way to grab the current URL and title of the page that the add-in part is residing on. The add-in part is a Provider Hosted add-in with the main piece living outside of SharePoint. I am using JSOM at the moment to grab the Client Context and Web Context.

I understand that the cross domain scripting is preventing me from using traditional `window.top.location.href`

Does anyone know of any tips or tricks that I may be missing to grab information that would otherwise be relatively easy to grab?

SharePoint is essentially using Cross-Domain scripting and a proxy page to share information between SharePoint and Azure. I need to grab the parent window of the iFrame of the proxy page.

I have an app that is attempting to track which page (title and URL) the action within the app was taken upon. Think of a survey. The information is added to a database related to the user. The add-in can be added to any page on the Site Collection.

Comment: If you have access to the other piece that does "live in SharePoint", can't you write the window location to a variable and access it / pass it?

Comment: That MIGHT work... but I believe the proxy page scrubs requests and only allows pre-determined parameters through. I'll try that route again.